# How to extract the feature map of certain layer in YOLOv8?

Tags: yolo, feature-extraction

I am doing a research on multi-task learning and I want to extract the feature map from the heads of YOLOv8 for comparison. I am modifying the tutorial from [here](https://ravivaishnav20.medium.com/visualizing-feature-maps-using-pytorch-12a48cd1e573) with YOLOv8n instead of the ResNet18 model used.

```
model = YOLO('models/yolov8n.pt')
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=0., std=1.)
])
image = Image.open(str('images/puppies.jpg'))
image = transform(image)
image = image.unsqueeze(0)
feature_map = model.model.model[15](image)
feature_map.shape
```

Error:
[image: Error]
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [128, 64, 3, 3], expected input[1, 3, 224, 224] to have 64 channels, but got 3 channels instead

I read the YOLOv8 architecture and suspect that image passed into the model is constant and does not change which is expected from the layers (Correct me if I'm wrong). The reason is because the code works when I want to extract feature from layer before any concatenation occurs. I pretty sure that my code is wrong but not sure how to implement it correctly.

Remarks: I am referring to the YOLOv8 architecture from RangeKing.
[image: YOLOv8 Architecture]